# Asking me for CucumberContextConfiguration when I already have

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I currently working on integration testing of one the Restful APIs. I have received an exception asking me to `annotate a glue class` using @CucumberContextConfiguration. At the moment, I have

**ApplicationTests.java**

```java
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {VehicleRegApplication.class, 
    VehicleRegApplicationTests.class, 
    CucumberSpringConfiguration.class})
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/Features", 
    glue = {"com.vehiclereg.StepDefinitions"}, 
    plugin = {"pretty"})
public class VehicleRegApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

**CucumberSpringConfiguration.java** in the same folder as the `ApplicationTests.java`

```java
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```

I have `cucumber-java`, `cucumber-spring`, `cucumber-junit`, `junit` injected. I have done what the exception says and when I run the test the same error comes back.

```
io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.
```

I wonder if I have done something wrong?

Comment: Is the cucumber context configuration on the glue path?

Comment: Maybe example help: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/spring

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Ah no.

Comment: @lojza Will look at it.

Comment: Which cucumber version you are using? Are you using JUnit4 or Junit5? What is your SpringBoot version?

Comment: Can't think on top of my head (in work laptop) but pretty sure it is the newest one for Cucumber. I am using Junit5. For Spring Boot I think it is 2.3.5.